# Can checkbox groups recognize repeat region results?

Tags: html, mysql, checkbox

So far, on every search I've tried to do it's all about how to read checkbox results into an array or database. I will get to that part of my webpage eventually, but at the moment I'm trying to solve something that I've not managed to find anywhere.

What I want to know is, can I create a checkbox field that can recognize individual results inside a repeat region to then write into a database? I shall explain using a screenshot of my test page as it currently stands:

[image: Test page]

The classes in the red box come from a repeat region that lists all the classes in the subject area and year group chosen (printed at the top-left corner of the page). The qualifications in the green box consist of several checkboxes where the user can assign certain qualifications to classes. Once the user has chosen the correct combinations of classes/qualifications, they can press the 'Assign' button to insert these combinations into a table in the database.

Is there a way that the checkboxes can recognize what 'row' of the repeat region they link to (E.G. the first row of checkboxes will relate to Class 10C/Ms1), or will I have to hard code this into the query? (For the prototype that's not a problem atm, but once we start filling out more subject areas and year groups it would make much more sense for it to be done dynamically)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a array in the name attribute of the checkboxes. For example it could look like this:

```
name="classes[10c/ms1][]"
```

Then when you post your form you will get a array for each class with the options that are checked.

Comment: Superb - Could that also be done with a variable by any chance? So that once new subjects and classes come into play it's still the same form, or does it have to manually be entered in?

Comment: Yeh you just need to echo out the variable that holds the class name. For example name="classes[<?php echo $classname; ?>][]". If your using PHP of course!

Comment: Groovy - I will look into this when I return from my business trip next week. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No worries. If you run into any issues give me a shout and i'll help best I can!